# What are the maximum and minimum sizes of a segment on the 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, memory-segmentation

What is the minimum and maximum size of a segment on the 8086? And, due to the minimum, what is the maximum number of separate segments that we can have? there is no need that all are active at a single time. (overlapping is acceptable)

Comment: Hey, [look what I found](http://www.eazynotes.com/notes/microprocessor/slides/memory-segmentation-of-8086.pdf) by simply *copy-pasting the full text of this question into Google*. It contains an exact answer to your question, BTW.

Comment: Good question, see my reply. I have no idea of why people downvoted the question.

Comment: @CodyGray, unless the title was changed, I do not see the slides you linked mentioning minimum size of  the segment, i.e. it does not mention 8086 not having a **segment limit**, which was mentioned by maxim's answer.

Answer (score 7):

The 8086 segment registers are 16-bit therefore there can be 65536 segments - but they overlap. The 20-bit physical address is obtained by shifting the segment register left 4 bits and adding the address offset. That means a segment may start at any 16-byte alignment. From the overlap it follows that there are many ways to addess one memory location, for example `0000:0010` and `0001:0000` address the same location.

Because the address offset is also 16 bits, the addressable size of any segment is 65536 bytes. So the maximum size of a segment is 65536 bytes, and the smallest is 16 bytes - though on the 8086 the entire segment may be read/written with no protection.

Your last question "the maximum number of separate segments" is 16 *separate* segments. Any more and they will overlap.

Comment: "...and the smallest is 16 bytes" This makes no sense in relation to the hardware. It's true when dealing with the sections (also called segments) of a program.

Comment: @SepRoland, just trying to answer the question. The smallest possible segment is 16 bytes because that is the resolution of the segment registers. If the designers had intended there to be 16 non-overlapping segments (as implied in another answer), they would have given the segment registers only 4 bits, not 16.

Comment: @niloofarlatifian you now changed the question, please don't shift the sand under our feet. The maximum number of segments is 65536. On 8086 there is no such thing as an "active segment". The segment registers provide a way to address 1MB of memory.

Comment: Well, the question change may have been partially my fault. I removed and slightly reworded a portion that didn't make any sense, but apparently there was a question embedded in there. Niloofar edited it back in. (No idea about this latest "overlapping is acceptable" edit, though.)

Comment: @CodyGray no prob. Re the separate/overlap: at school I remember our PE teacher would come up with gems such as "spread out in a bunch" and "double up into threes" ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the real mode, segments have no “size”: the memory is not partioned by segments in the `real mode`. A segment is a part of larger entity: `segment+offset` – that are both used to calculate the effective address. These are both segment and offset that allow the CPU to calculate the address of a memory byte, and byte is a minimum unit that can be addressed on Intel platform. About the “segment+offset” programmers also say that they comprise a `“far pointer”`. To the contrary, a `“near pointer”` is a relative pointer comparing to the other pointer, that both have the same segment. So, the "far" pointer is a pointer consisting of a 16-bit segment selector and a 16-bit (or a 32-bit, depending on mode) offset, so the total far pointer size was 32-bit in 16-bit mode and 48-bit in 32-bit mode. The segment selector is loaded into a special segment register before accessing the memory from the “far” pointer. There are the special instructions to load a far pointer at once. On `Intel 8086`, most popular instruction were `LDS` and `LES`, that load the “far” pointer from memory to the pair of registers: one segment register (`DS` or `ES`) and one general (offset) register. There are also versions for the other registers: `LFS`, `LGS` and `LSS` for `FS`, `GS` and `SS` segment registers respectively (introduced in `Intel 80386`). Segments are extremely useful in 16-bit mode, be it 16-bit real mode or 16-bit protected mode. In 16-bit real mode, the value of segment register was multiplied by 16 and then the offset was added – this is how the effective address was calculated. But, again, since the memory in real mode was not “segmented”, there were no minimum or maximum size of a segment. In 16-bit real mode, if you load FFFF to both DS and SI registers, you can theoretically access (16*0xFFFF)+FFFF = **1114096**th byte of memory (some practical restrictions applied like the so-called `A20-line` etc) – or about **1 Megabyte**.

Under the `32-bit mode`, there is almost no need in segment registers, since all segment registers are essentially point to the same locations, so there is no need to load segment registers.

Under `64-bit modes`, these instructions are not implemented, their opcode gave access violations. Since Intel's implementation of `VEX` - "vector extensions - (`SSE2`), Intel took their opcodes of `LDS` and `LES` and started using them for `VEX` prefixes. As a result, 256-bit `AVX` (`YMM`) registers are only available in 64-bit mode.

In `protected mode`, there is such a notion as a segment size, but, again, there is no minimum size, or the minimum size was the minimum allocation unit of the architecture, e.g. **16 byte** in `16-bit mode` or **4 kilobytes** in `32-bit mode`. In protected mode, the segment register holds not a value multiplied by 16 as in 16-bit real mode, but an index in the selector table. Since the introduction of the Intel `80286's protected mode`, extends the processor's address space from about 1 megabyte to 224 bytes (16 megabytes), but not by using larger offsets. Instead, the 16-bit segment registers now contain an index into a table of segment descriptors containing 24-bit base addresses to which the offset is added. The maximum segment size was 64 Kilobytes. In the `Intel 80386` and later processors, protected mode retains the segmentation mechanism of 80286 protected mode, but a paging unit has been added as a second layer of address translation between the segmentation unit and the physical bus. Also, importantly, address offsets are 32-bit (instead of 16-bit), and the segment base in each segment descriptor is also 32-bit (instead of 24-bit). Maximum segment size, as a result, have been increased to a theoretical maximum of **4 GB**. Interestingly, contrary to the belief, there is no physical limit of 4GB for 32-bit operating systems. For example, 32-bit Server Operating Systems like Microsoft Windows Server 2008 32-bit can access up to **64 GB** (Windows Server 2008 Enterprise and Datacenter editions) – by means of Physical Address Extension (PAE), which was first introduced by Intel in the Pentium Pro, and later by AMD in the Athlon processor - It defines a page table hierarchy of three levels, with table entries of 64 bits each instead of 32, allowing these CPUs to directly access a physical address space larger than 4 gigabytes – so theoretically, a 32-bit OS can access 2^64 bytes theoretically, or 17,179,869,184 gigabytes, but the segment is limited by **4 GB**.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of each segment is 64kB because offset is of 16 bit so each segment has 2^16 bytes = 64KB. minimum size of segment is 16B.

Answer (score 0):

The max size is 64K. There is no minimum - you can use only first byte, but the segment is always 64K. Maybe the exception are the last segments - the latest (0xFFFF) is 16 bytes, before the latest are 32, 48, 64 bytes... Generally, 8086 segments are method for addressing of more than 64K with 16 bit address registers.

Comment: Segments above 0xF000 wrap around through zero on 8086 (on 80286+, they access bytes above 0x1000000. For compatibility, PC's could disable A20, to get the 8086 compatible wrap around).

Answer (score -2):

In 8086 microprocessor the total memory addressing capability is 1MB. For representing 1MB a minimum of 5 hex digits are required i.e. 20 bits.  8086 microprocessor has fourteen 16 bit registers (i.e. there are no registers for representing 20 bit address). So, the total memory can be divided into 16 separate logical segments and each segment capacity is 64KB (i.e. `16 * 64 KB = 1MB`).

Comment: "...divided into 16 logical segments" The memory is divided in 65536 segments that heavily overlap.

Comment: 14 registers?  Are you counting FLAGS and IP?  8 general-purpose and one instruction pointer that can be involved in the "offset" part of an address (actually only some of them can be used in 16-bit addressing modes), and 4 segment registers that can be the "segment" part.  FLAGS isn't involved in addressing.